# Парсинг данных веб-страницы в текстовый файл, стандартными средствами

Tags: javascript, html, css

Перед мной стоит задача парсинга веб-страниц обращений на предприятии используя стандартные средства имеющиеся на любом пк в офисе, так как нельзя нарушать политику безопасности, на данных страницах в том числе хранятся персональные данные.

Нужно вывести определенные данные, строки, такие как номер обращения, фио, почта и тд в текстовый документ для дальнейшего взаимодействия с ними.

Сложность в том что нельзя использовать библиотеки, доступ в интернет и прочие внешние инструменты.
В наличии только браузер.

Пример строк, которые необходимо вывести в файл:

```html
//1
<h4 class="voffset"> 560066078 </h4>

//2
<td>
<a href="https://gg.com" target="_blank"> Иванов Иван </a>
</td>

//3
<td>
<a href="mailto:ivan@mail.ru" ivan@mail.ru </a>
<br>
<a href="mailto:ivan2@mail.ru" ivan2@mail.ru </a>
</td>
```

Comment: А откуда берутся страницы для парсинга, если доступа в интернет нет?

Comment: Вам поможет следующий комплект:
* консоль браузера - 1 шт.
* знание javascript - 1 шт.
* знание структуры документа и понимание как добраться до нужного HTML-элемента - 1 шт.
* текстовый редактор (для сохранения скриптиков в файлик) - 1шт.
Парсите что вам надо, складываете в текстовую переменную в нужном виде, копируете результат из консоли, сохраняете в файл. Сделать можете хоть CSV, хоть свой HTML, хоть XML.

Comment: Интернет на предприятии есть, но доступ к нему ограничен, если использовать сторонние сайты, прибежит специалист информационной безопасности и скажет ай ай ай